THD Value of 3-level Modified Sine Wave
"The lowest THD for a three-step modified sine wave is 30% when the pulses are at 130 degrees width of each electrical cycle." This sentence is taken from this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter

This picture is taken from same link.
Which one is true?
I understood the first statement above; indeed, I calculated the THD value to be 29.11% for this specific case. Also,I calculate THD for other values. Actually,this thd value is the lowest.
If this value is already the smallest, how could you obtain a smaller value from it?
I use this equation to calculate THD. This equation is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion

After some intermediate steps I get this final formula:

where alpha is the angle of zero voltage on each end of the pulse

It depends how you define THD and how you calculated it.

I defined it as a expression that varies according to the alpha parameter. And using the formula above, I calculated THD by inputting alpha values.
